# Map Lowercase Alphabet to Integers

Tags: python

i cant make a dict where to every one letter will be a value in the n + 1 format, start from 1.
this is my code:

```
dict1 = {x: y for x in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstunvwxyz' for y in range(1, 20, 1)}
print(dict1)
```

i get it:

```
{'a': 19, 'b': 19, 'c': 19, 'd': 19, 'e': 19, 'f': 19, 'g': 19, 'h': 19, 'i': 19, 'j': 19, 'k': 19, 'l': 19, 'm': 19, 'n': 19, 'o': 19, 'p': 19, 'q': 19, 'r': 19, 's': 19, 't': 19, 'u': 19, 'v': 19, 'w': 19, 'y': 19, 'z': 19}
```

can u tell me why and how to get it: `{'a': 1, 'b':2...`

Comment: what range should i make

Comment: Please see my post below and ask any questions.

Comment: `for x in ... for y in ...` is a nested loop.  You get the first value of `y` paired with each possible value of `x`, and then the second value of `y` paired with each value of `x`, and so on.

Comment: thank u i understand everything, just didnt know about enumerate function before

Comment: bro i cant just need to wait 5 mins bcs i just registered in this website

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the tools provided by Python to make this easier to implement and read. First, don't hardcode the lowercase alphabet, use the stdlib `string`. Next, don't do the arithmetic yourself, it's easy to get wrong: there are 26 letters but `range(1, 20, 1)` generates only 19 digits. You also have a typo in your alphabet (I assume): `tunvw`. Lastly, use `enumerate()` which generates `tuple`s consisting of an element of a sequence and an auto-incrementing integer, and use the `start` keyword argument to set the starting integer value.

```py
import string
d = {x: y for x, y in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, start=1)}
```

---

Your code doesn't produce the result you want because for each integer from 1 to 19, it assigns the integer to the value for each key ('a', 'b', 'c', etc.). The first iteration of the outer `for` produces the dictionary `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, etc.}`. Then, each subsequent iteration of the outer `for` overwrites these values with the new integer: 2, 3, 4, etc.

This is easy to see if we convert the comprehension to loops:

```py
d = {}
for y in range(1, 20, 1):
    for x in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
        d[x] = y
    print(d)
```

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'f': 1, 'g': 1, 'h': 1, 'i': 1, 'j': 1, 'k': 1, 'l': 1, 'm': 1, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 1, 'q': 1, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 1, 'w': 1, 'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'z': 1}
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 2, 'e': 2, 'f': 2, 'g': 2, 'h': 2, 'i': 2, 'j': 2, 'k': 2, 'l': 2, 'm': 2, 'n': 2, 'o': 2, 'p': 2, 'q': 2, 'r': 2, 's': 2, 't': 2, 'u': 2, 'v': 2, 'w': 2, 'x': 2, 'y': 2, 'z': 2}
{'a': 3, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 3, 'e': 3, 'f': 3, 'g': 3, 'h': 3, 'i': 3, 'j': 3, 'k': 3, 'l': 3, 'm': 3, 'n': 3, 'o': 3, 'p': 3, 'q': 3, 'r': 3, 's': 3, 't': 3, 'u': 3, 'v': 3, 'w': 3, 'x': 3, 'y': 3, 'z': 3}
...
{'a': 19, 'b': 19, 'c': 19, 'd': 19, 'e': 19, 'f': 19, 'g': 19, 'h': 19, 'i': 19, 'j': 19, 'k': 19, 'l': 19, 'm': 19, 'n': 19, 'o': 19, 'p': 19, 'q': 19, 'r': 19, 's': 19, 't': 19, 'u': 19, 'v': 19, 'w': 19, 'x': 19, 'y': 19, 'z': 19}
```

---

**edit:** You don't need a comprehension to do this. There is another, pretty clean solution:

```py
import string
d = dict(enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, start=1))
```

This solution relies on the `dict(iterable)` constructor:

```
Help on class dict in module builtins:

class dict(object)
 |  dict() -> new empty dictionary
 |  dict(mapping) -> new dictionary initialized from a mapping object's
 |      (key, value) pairs
 |  dict(iterable) -> new dictionary initialized as if via:
 |      d = {}
 |      for k, v in iterable:
 |          d[k] = v
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to zip the alphabet and the range to see what you get like that:

```
z1 = zip('abcdefghijklmnopqrstunvwxyz', range(1, 28))
```

Which will give us:

```
for tup in z1:
    print(tup)
```

## Output:

```
('a', 1)
('b', 2)
('c', 3)
('d', 4)
('e', 5)
('f', 6)
('g', 7)
('h', 8)
('i', 9)
('j', 10)
('k', 11)
('l', 12)
('m', 13)
('n', 14)
('o', 15)
('p', 16)
('q', 17)
('r', 18)
('s', 19)
('t', 20)
('u', 21)
('n', 22)
('v', 23)
('w', 24)
('x', 25)
('y', 26)
('z', 27)
```

Now you can assign each element of each tuple to x, y:

```
d1 = {x: y for x, y in zip('abcdefghijklmnopqrstunvwxyz', range(1, 28))}
```

## Output:

```
print(d1)
{'a': 1,
 'b': 2,
 'c': 3,
 'd': 4,
 'e': 5,
 'f': 6,
 'g': 7,
 'h': 8,
 'i': 9,
 'j': 10,
 'k': 11,
 'l': 12,
 'm': 13,
 'n': 22,
 'o': 15,
 'p': 16,
 'q': 17,
 'r': 18,
 's': 19,
 't': 20,
 'u': 21,
 'v': 23,
 'w': 24,
 'x': 25,
 'y': 26,
 'z': 27}
```